# Node JS request blocking other requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, mean-stack, es6-promise

I have created Node JS app, i am explicitly downloading more than 100000 records from database. While the request is in proceeding, i try to login in the same application from another browser it wont respond unless the previous request is completed. Any idea ? Anything to do with event loop or threads ??
So here is my logic.
I make a get request to my API in Step 1, API calls database layer in Step 2. Database is returning only 21 records, i am explicitly looping 100000*21 to make heavy rendering just to test the load on json2csv. While doing so, the other requests to server will not respond until the last processing completes.

```
Step 1:

router.get('/report/downloadOverdueTrainings/:criteria', function (req, res, next) {
        var overDueTrainings = [];
        var reportManager = new ReportManager();
        var result = reportManager.getOverdueTrainings(JSON.parse(req.params.criteria));
        result.then(function (result) {
            var fields = ['Over Due Trainings'];
            for (var i = 0; i < 100000; i++) { //Testing purpose
                for (var training of result) {
                    overDueTrainings.push({
                        'Over Due Trainings': training.OverDueTrainings
                    })
                }
            }
            json2csv({
                data: overDueTrainings,
                fields: fields
            }, function (err, csv) {
                if (err)
                    throw err;
                res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=OverdueTrainings.csv');
                res.set('Content-Type', 'text/csv');
                res.send(csv);
            });
        }).catch(function (err) {
            next(err);
        });
    });

Step 2: Database Logic
var xtrDatabaseConnection =require('./xtrDatabaseConnection').XTRDatabaseConnection;
       ReportData.prototype.getOverdueTrainings = async function (params) {
        var connection = new xtrDatabaseConnection();
        var sequelize = connection.getSequelize();
        try {
            var query = "CALL report_getOverdueTrainings(:p_CourseCode,:p_Revision,:p_RevisionNo,:p_UserGroup,:p_Username,:p_Status,:p_SortColoumnNo,:p_SortColoumnDirection,:p_callType,:p_StartIndex,:p_PageSize)";
            var replacements = {
                p_CourseCode: params.CourseCode,
                p_Revision: params.Revision,
                p_RevisionNo: (params.RevisionNo == '' || params.RevisionNo == null) ? 0 : params.RevisionNo,
                p_UserGroup: params.UserGroup,
                p_Username: params.Username,
                p_Status: params.Status,
                p_SortColoumnNo: params.SortColoumnNo,
                p_SortColoumnDirection: params.SortColoumnDirection,
                p_callType: params.callType,
                p_StartIndex: params.startIndex,
                p_PageSize: params.pageSize
            };
            //console.log(replacements);
            return await connection.executeQuerySequelize(sequelize, query, Sequelize.QueryTypes.RAW, replacements);
        } catch (e) {
            throw (e);
        } finally {
            //To close connections
            sequelize.connectionManager.close().then(() => console.log('Connection Closed'));
        }
    }




XTRDatabaseConnection.prototype.executeQuerySequelize = function (sequelize, query, queryType, replacements) {
    return sequelize.authenticate()
        .then(() => {
            return sequelize.query(query, {
                replacements: replacements,
                type: queryType
            }).
            then(result => result)
                .catch(err => {
                    throw (err);
                });
        })
        .catch(err => {
            xtrUtility.logErrorsToWinstonTransports('Unable to connect to the database or some error occurred while executing your query. ', err);
            throw new AppError(err, "dbError", "Unable to connect to the database or some error occurred while executing your query.");
        });
}
```

Comment: what error did you got

Comment: I am not getting any error, when i generate request for downloading csv file, in the mean time perform any other function it will not respond until the file gets download. It means something is blocking.

Comment: it is because of for loop it blocked the event loop you can try use of cluster or child process

Comment: are you using express?

Comment: How long it take to complete the database task ? If that is completed your does login works fine ?.

Comment: yes i am using Express.

Comment: There are only 21 records, they merely take milliseconds. I am looping 100000 time on 21 records to test json2csv.

Answer (score 1):

This is blocking:

```
    for (var i = 0; i < 100000; i++) { //Testing purpose
        for (var training of result) {
            overDueTrainings.push({
                'Over Due Trainings': training.OverDueTrainings
            })
        }
    }
```

until the execution is finished.

also

```
 var result = reportManager.getOverdueTrainings(JSON.parse(req.params.criteria));
    result.then(function (result) {
 /****/
 return await connection.executeQuerySequelize(sequelize, query, Sequelize.QueryTypes.RAW, replacements);
```

Comment: Not sure why this is downvoted because it is indeed blocking and no other Javascript in the node.js process (including any other events or requests) can run while this loop is running.

Comment: So how can i test this as alternative to loop??

Comment: @jfriend00 yeah, don't know why, you are right. @saad-zulfiqar you should put the testing `blocking` part into backend which really blocks

Answer (score 1):

NodeJS is single-thread, single process. As long as a javascript function is running, nothing else can run. This is by design. The event loop will only kick in again once your functions have stopped executing.

Comment: I totally denied your answer with respect to question. There are many approach in node.js to do so . Although i agreed what you have written.

Comment: There wasn't really a question, but I took it as the OP asking why it was blocking. I think it's important for any aspiring node.js developer to understand the javascript event loop before jumping on workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

Node.js is working on single thread. So you need use it for small process with async calls. When you use async/await you are blocking the callback function.

So you need to use your database functions as promise. It will work async.

```
.query('CALL someFunction()')
.then(function(response){
      //done
    }).error(function(err){
     //error
});
```

But there is a problem about it. You need to load 21 times your result. So in this case you need to use recursive function. When you finished recursive call you can send your data to client as async.